# post throttling using php mysql and an epoch timestamp not functioning

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to throttle posts by users via php, mysql, and an epoch timestamp in my database stored in the row `timestamp` (ex: `1406059107`).

My script executes as intended the first time and throttles the user for 60 seconds, but after that I can literally flood the server with posts since the throttling stops functioning.

I tried using `ASC` instead of `DESC` without success.

```
$sql = "SELECT timestamp FROM phpbb_schedule WHERE username = " . (int) $user->data['user_id'] . " ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

$result = $db->sql_query_limit($sql, 1);
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
$db->sql_freeresult($result);

if (time() - $row['timestamp'] < 60)
{
    header( 'Location: someurl.php' );
    die ('Your can only input one request every 60 seconds.');
}
else
{
    echo 'success some other code goes here that inputs the data into the db and redirects this to another page';
}
```

> Note: The issue has been resolved I didn't use `ORDER by timestamp` and a syntax error had occurred (see comments).

Comment: turn on all the error and `if (time() - $row['timestamp'] <  60 )`

Comment: Thank you fixed the syntax error, but it's still inserting despite 60 seconds not elapsing.

Comment: I manually executed the query and got the right output. Full texts  timestamp
 Edit Edit  Edit Inline Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  1406059107
 Edit Edit  Edit Inline Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  1406060336
 Edit Edit  Edit Inline Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  1406060348
 Edit Edit  Edit Inline Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  1406063335
 Edit Edit  Edit Inline Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  1406063346
 Edit Edit  Edit Inline Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  1406063358

Comment: It functions only the first time for 60 seconds... after that I can flood the server with posts... I figured the issue meant I needed to change DESC to ASC, but that didn't help.

Comment: Is it possible the query isn't running more than once? so `$row['timestamp']` is not changed after it is initially set?

Comment: Maybe I should change ORDER BY status DESC"; to ORDER BY timestamp DESC"; I just noticed that I'll check your suggestion too thank you

Comment: yeah ORDER BY timestamp fixed the issue, but I did have a syntax issue in my original post so thank you for resolving it Abhik and thank you sharf for offering help too